# obj-c : iphone programming, call method with 2 parameters

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameters

i have a method that call another method with 1 parameter to another class. It is working perfectly but now i need 1 more parameters this is my code :

i am getting a 'addobject may not respond'

test.m

calling method :

```
DrunkeNewIdeaAppDelegate *appDelegate = (DrunkeNewIdeaAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  Testes *myLevelObject = (Testes *)appDelegate.testViewController1;
  [myLevelObject addobject:rephereanswer,nbimportant];
```

method called :

testes.h

```
-(void)addobject:(double)rephereanswer:(double)nbimportant;
```

testes.m

```
-(void)addobject:(double)rephereanswer:(double)nbimportant{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of your method is actually `addObject: :`. Parameters are preceded by colons, so you'd call your method like so:

```
[myLevelObject addobject:rephereanswer :nbimportant];
```

However, in Objective-C, the prevailing style is to name *all* of your parameters, so you'd probably want to change your method to this:

```
- (void)addobject:(double)rephereanswer otherParam:(double)nbimportant;
```

In which case you'd call it like this:

```
[myLevelObject addobject:rephereanswer otherParam:nbimportant];
```

(A more descriptive name than `otherParam` is desirable, too.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
[myLevelObject addobject:rephereanswer :nbimportant];
```